# Replacing only the first string in xml filefor new one in Powershell

Tags: powershell, replace

I have a powershell script which replace every occurance in file:

```
$destination_file =  'd:\2.xml'
(Get-Content $original_file) | ForEach-Object {
    $_.replace('<Id>10810</Id>', '<Id>107502</Id>').replace('<Id>10811</Id>', '<Id>107503</Id>').replace('<Id>10812</Id>', '<Id>107504</Id>').replace('<Id>10813</Id>', '<Id>107505</Id>').replace('<Id>10765</Id>', '<Id>107506</Id>').replace('<Id>10766</Id>', '<ParentId>107613</ParentId>').replace('<ParentId>11818</ParentId>', '<ParentId>107647</ParentId>').replace('<ParentId>11818</ParentId>', '<ParentId>107001</ParentId>').replace('<ParentId>5002</ParentId>', '<ParentId>107404</ParentId>').replace('<ParentId>11564</ParentId>', '<LogicalParentID>107404</LogicalParentID>').replace('<LogicalParentID>5002</LogicalParentID>', '<LogicalParentID>107228</LogicalParentID>').replace('<LogicalParentID>10808</LogicalParentID>', '<LogicalParentID>107500</LogicalParentID>')
 } | Set-Content $destination_File
```

Every xml node has got many atributes like:

```
<id>9203</id>
<ParentId>107404</ParentId>
<LogicalParentID>107500</LogicalParentID>
and many more
```

I want to replace only those 3 in every section. The script I made replace all occurance "107404" in hole file.
**I want to replace only one ocurance. How can do this, please help?**

Comment: It's an XML document, so edit it as XML instead of doing string replacement.

Comment: Show more of the XML file and make it clear which ParentId tag should get a new value and which should not, based on ??